# Linq to SQL and using ToList, how many DB calls are made?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I got a function like this

```
    public List<Code> GetCodes()
    {
        return _db.Codes.Select(p => p).ToList();
    }
```

I have 160,000 records in this table which contains 2 columns.

Then I also loop through it as follows..

```
List<Code> CodeLastDigits = CodeDataProvider.GetCodes();
```

And then loop through it

```
 foreach (var postCodeLastDigit in PostCodeLastDigits)
```

I am just trying to understand how many times a call is made to the database to retrieve those records, and want to make sure it only happens once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq will delay the call to the database until you give it a reason to go.

In your case, you are giving a reason in the `ToList()` method.

Once you call `ToList()` you will have all the items in memory and wont be hitting the database again.

You didnt mention which DB platform you are using, but if it is SQL Server, you can use SQL Server profiler to watch your queries to the database.  This is a good way to see how many calls and what sql is being run by linq to SQL.  As @acfrancis notes below, LinqPad can also do this.

For SQL Server, here is a good tutorial on [creating a trace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047.aspx)

Comment: To confirm that, you can run a profiler on your database or use a tool like LinqPad.

Comment: ok great thanks makes sense. In terms of using large collections is List<T> the right collection to use ? Or would for example a Dictionary be better for performance ?

Comment: @StevieB if you are looping i dont think you would see much of a difference.  but if you know which key you want a dictionary is much faster.

Comment: Well for example the Code table consists of ID | Code so I guess it is suitable for a Dictionary but ye I am just looping through the collection. I don't have a situation where I am looking up a particular key

Comment: putting all that data INTO a dictionary takes time too.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `ToList()`, it's going to hit the database.  In this case, it appears like you'll just be hitting the database once to populate your CodeLastDigits.  As long as you aren't hitting the database again in your foreach, you should be good.

As long as you have the full version of SQl Server, you can run Sql Server Profiler while going through your code to see what's happening on the database.

Answer (score 1):

Probably once.  But the more complete answer is that it depends, and you should be familiar with the case where even a simple access pattern like this one can result in many, many round trips to the database.

It's not likely a table named `codes` contains any complex types, but if it did, you'd want to watch out.  Depending on how you access the properties of a `code` object, you could incur extra hits to the database if you don't use [LoadWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548760%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properly.

Consider an example where you have a Code object, which contains a CodeType object (also mapped to a table) in a class structure like this:

```
class Code {
   CodeType type;
}
```

If you don't load CodeType objects with Code objects, Linq to SQL would contact the database on every iteration of your loop if CodeType is referenced inside the loop, because it would lazy-load the object only when needed.  Watch out for this, and do some research on the LoadWith<> method and its use to get comfortable that you're not running into this situation.

```
foreach (x in PostCodeDigits) {
    Print(x.type);
}
```

Comment: Good stuff, didn't know this !